# TextMate and compiling options

Tags: textmate, compilation, gsl

I'm writing a code in C++ with the support of the GNU Scientific Libraries. I've properly installed them and in order to compile them from the Terminal I just have to write the following:

```
g++  $(gsl-config --cflags) filename.cpp $(gsl-config --libs)
```

Now, I'm a TextMate user, and I would like to modify the standard Run command from the C bundle in order to compile my cpp files with the right gsl options. The problem is the TextMate.Executor function, that I totally ignore and for which I haven't found any exhaustive reference.

Here's what I have tried:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/executor"
require ENV["TM_SUPPORT_PATH"] + "/lib/tm/save_current_document"

mode = ENV["TM_SCOPE"].slice(/.*?\bsource\.((?:obj)?c(\+\+)?)/, 1)


case mode
when "c"
  g    = "GCC"
  env  = "C"
  ext  = "c"
  lang = "c"
when "c++"
  g    = "GXX"
  env  = "CXX"
  ext  = "cc"
  lang = "c++"
when "objc"
  g    = "GCC"
  env  = "OBJC"
  ext  = "m"
  lang = "objective-c"
when "objc++"
  g    = "GXX"
  env  = "OBJCXX"
  ext  = "mm"
  lang = "objective-c++"
end

TextMate.save_current_document(ext)
TextMate::Executor.make_project_master_current_document

flags = ENV["TM_#{env}_FLAGS"] || "-Wall -include stdio.h $(gsl-config --cflags) "
args = [ENV["TM_#{g}"] || g.downcase.gsub("x", "+"), flags + " -x #{lang}", ENV["TM_FILEPATH"]+" $(gsl-config --libs)"] 

TextMate::Executor.run(args, :version_args => ["--version"])
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but might instead be a more preferable thing to do (and, arguably the more recommended thing to do?)

Create a Makefile for your code. Here's a stripped-down version of mine:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -L/opt/local/lib -I/opt/local/include -I$(SRC_DIR)
GSLFLAGS = -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -I/opt/local/include/gsl
EXEC = mRVM
SRC_DIR = ./src
OUTPUT_DIR = ./bin

all: $(EXEC)

clean:
    -rm $(OUTPUT_DIR)/test
    -rm $(OUTPUT_DIR)/*.exe

$(EXEC): 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(GSLFLAGS) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(EXEC) $(SRC_DIR)/main.cc
```

Now in your "project," navigate to the Makefile and press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>